# Keycloack - Grant access to a client to a group of users

Tags: keycloak

I've created many clients on a single realm. How can i get access to a client only to certain users or a group using openid and OAuth 2.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a user-based Authorization policy.

1. For this first, you have to enable the Authorization Enabled option
   from clients

[image]

2. You may see Authorization Tab now. On this tab, you can view the list of previously created policies as well as create and edit a policy. To create a new policy, select a policy type from the Create policy item list in the upper right corner.
3. For your requirements, you can add User-Based Or Group-Based Authorization policy. Screenshot for user based Authorization Policy Below
   [image]

Comment: I use this solution but when in the form of login/password i can use credential of a user not authorized to connect. In the log of keycloack i see "17:56:52,456 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (default task-1) KC-SERVICES0091: Request is missing scope 'openid' so it's not treated as OIDC, but just pure OAuth2 request."  I'm using oauth2-keycloak PHP library to connect

Comment: Side note for those wanting to use different authentication method: Authorization option is only available for OpenID Connect clients, not SAML.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak do not support group specific auth policies over AccessType being public. But if we set the accessType to confidential then we it will ask for a clientSecret in the login and we will end up with this.

[KEYCLOAK: Client secret not provided in request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62298549/keycloak-client-secret-not-provided-in-request)